# Sunspot_Solr with Rails - How to setting slorconfig.xml highlighting output length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, solr, sunspot-solr

I set the gem 'sunspot_rails' and gem 'sunspot_solr'
highlighting can correct output,
but the sentence was too short.

I have tried to change slorconfig.xml

`<fragmenter name="regex" class="solr.highlight.RegexFragmenter">
    <int name="hl.fragsize">100</int> # before 70`

command

> bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:stop
>
> bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start
>
> rake sunspot:solr:reindex

But without any change.

command> reindex he output

[Simple Form] Simple Form is not configured in the application and will use the default values. Use `rails generate simple_form:install` to generate the Simple Form configuration.
Skipping progress bar: for progress reporting, add gem 'progress_bar' to your Gemfile

please help me Thanks!

ubuntu 14.04
ruby 2.1
rails 4.1